# Carrier Central Air Conditioner Model 38CKC042-340 with 35/5 instead of 40/5

Tags: hvac

I have this unit 
Carrier Central Air Conditioner Model 38CKC042-340

I was looking at http://www.repairclinic.com/Shop-For-Parts/a41b370d1182307/Model-38CKC042340-Carrier-Central-Air-Conditioner-Parts and it says i need "Capacitor Dual 40 + 5 mfd 440 volt Round"

My existing Capacitor was 35/5 so i replaced with another TRCFD355 35/5 MFD Round Dual Motor Run Capacitor

Questions
1. Is there any issue with running 35/5 instead of 40/5 as suggested by Repair clinic

Answer (score -1):

Should be fine if you replaced a factory part with a part of the same size and configuration.